# Is it possible to make a crawlable AJAX web application WITHOUT using HTML snapshots?

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers, googlebot, ajax

Is it possible to make single page application (SPA) crawlable without HTML snapshots with help of HTML5 History API `pushState`?

I have found contradictory meanings. Can you support or refute one of them?

1. [*YES*, it's possible to make SPA crawlable w/o server rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437815/does-html5modetrue-affect-google-search-crawlers/32782081#32782081).

   The only explanation I found is - when Google crawler goes through `<a href="site.com/go">` it subscribes to [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) and waits you'll trigger HTML5 History `pushState`. After you get all async content, you trigger `pushState` and crawler start crawling.

   *Do really Google knows how to subscribe onpopstate events?*
2. *No*, that impossible. I came to the same conclusion, the same is said in [this article](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/). It says that `pushState` is a replacement of [hashbangs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) to make the same URL for both user and crawler.

**P.S.** If it's impossible with `pushState`, are there any other acceptable ways?

Answer (score -1):

Trying to answer my question, what I've read and understood. Correct me please if I'm wrong:

At some point of time Google decided: "why spend own server resources to execute JS if isomorphic get popular, let's force everyone to do JS on their own servers", and [depracated JS execution](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) by bots. Can't say if at this moment Google support JS, but it can stop supporting it any moment.

Moreover, I heard Google may degrade PageRank if you're not supporting server   rendering.

If to speak about [solution of making google bot waiting for AJAX content with History API `pushState`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437815/does-html5modetrue-affect-google-search-crawlers/32782081#32782081) - than yes that worked (or work if Google haven't stopped JS support yet). Does this solution need JS? Or in other words how google bot subscrite [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) event without JS?

*Conclusion:* Also there are another SEO besides Google, haven't any idea if they support JS. So my conclusion is that `pushState` solution is not reliable and unversal.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller pls look at my answer, am I right in my conclusion? Maybe you have something to add?

Comment: That ping won't notify anyone. Also, pinging a random person for help is discouraged.

Comment: @grgarside why a random person? We have a discussion in comments with Stephen, but looks like it was removed (don't know how)

Comment: Googlebot does execute JavaScript and render pages to see what text is visible to users.   Googlebot also supports URL changes with `pushState`.   It should be possible to build a site that Google understands using those mechanisms, but I don't have any experience doing so.

Comment: *At some point of time Google decided: "why spend own server resources to execute JS if isomorphic get popular, let's force everyone to do JS on their own servers", and depracated JS execution by bots* — The deprecated Ajax crawling scheme required people to generate the crawlable content on their own servers. So you're wrong about that.

Comment: *If to speak about solution of making google bot waiting for AJAX content with History API pushState - than yes that worked (or work if Google haven't stopped JS support yet). Does this solution need JS?* — The point of `pushState` is that you get to use real URLs, so you can do [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) which means that if the URL is requested directly (instead of being inserted with pushState) then you render the complete page on your server. So it doesn't need the client to support JS at all.

Comment: *So my conclusion is that pushState solution is not reliable and unversal.* — Only if you implement it incorrectly. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for addition! Yeah, my answer is wrong. Could you pls describe the scheme with more details, and I will accept your answer and delete mine.